# Is this code vulnerable to XSS? (Form auto-posts onload)

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I have some JavaScript which retrieves a user-submitted querystring value, sets a hidden field's VALUE to the parameter, then posts the form automatically.

This is all done on page load. Is there any potential for XSS?

```
<script>
    function autoSubmit(){
        var url = ... /* retrieve URL from querystring parameter */
        document.getElementById("txt").value = url;
        document.getElementById("myform").submit();
    }
</script>
<!-- ...... --->
<body onload="autoSubmit()">
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="POST" action="http://www.mysite.com/someform.php">
 <input id="txt" name="txt" type="hidden" value="" />
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You are not executing remote code anywhere and you aren't allowing users to enter their own Markup.
But are you sure you are concerned about XSS?

The site is likely vulnerable to some form of XSRF for the usual XSRF Reasons:

- I'm asuming (since you mentioned query parameters) you are loading this page via a HTTP GET, yet it directly leads to a POST which (likely) modifies data in some way. Users might be tricked into clicking a link with evil parameters (sessionstealing?)
- Again: Asuming you have not taken any other precautions, posting from a remote location might have the same effect.

More in depth anaylsis would require looking at your someform.php

Comment: You raise a good point about the potential for XSRF. However, I am assuming that someform.php is robust and can handle whatever data is sent to it.

Comment: Really, my question is, is there any danger in executing `hiddenfield.value=some_user_input;` ... it appears that it is safe.

Comment: Indeed it is. You are only modifying a (real!) attribute of the dom node, that's supposed to be safe on a conforming browser and I don't know of any browsers that get this wrong.

Answer (score -1):

ANY input from the client side is vulnerable to xss.  Any code to avoid this on the client side (hiding inputs, etc) can be easily bypassed by using FireFox poster.

I don't think what you have here (getting querystring parameter into variable and then submitting through form data) is particularly vulnerable to XSS just because exploiting that somehow would only allow the malicious user to mess up the rendering of their own view (in which case, who cares?).  Can I think of a specific value of the url parameter which will break the rendering of the page?  No.  Is it possible?  I don't know...but it doesn't matter.

It doesn't matter because that is not where XSS comes into play.  XSS vulnerabilities aren't manifested by a single user performing a form post.  They become a problem when the value of the input parameter in question is rendered to a place where users other than the malicious user can see it.  So, whether or not this exposes an XSS vulnerability is completely independent of the code you've provided here.  It depends on what you do with the post parameter from the form and how you render the contents of that value throughout your site.

Comment: I am asking if the code is vulnerable, not client input. Obviously, client input is a vector for XSS by definition. If you are saying the CODE is vulnerable, could you please provide a querystring input that will cause XSS with this code?